# How to search array of objects with two element in mongoose

Tags: node.js

I have this objects inside my model

```
{
    "name" : "one",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "foo" : "1",
            "bar" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "foo" : "1",
            "bar" : "3"
        }
    ]
},...
```

when I query

```
myModel.find({
    "items.foo": "1",
    "items.bar": "2"
}
```

results is object with name one which is correct,  but when I query

```
myModel.find({
    "items.foo": "1",
    "items.bar": "3"
}
```

it should not find any results, however, unexpectedly it again results in object with name one.
I tried this but the same results happened

```
myModel.find({
    $and :[{
    "items.foo": "1"},
    {"items.bar": "3"}
]}
```

any suggestions what should I do?

Comment: why it shouldn't find any thing? foo with 1 and bar with 3 is also present in array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should work :

```
myModel.find({
            items: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $and: [{
                            foo: "1"
                        },
                        {
                            bar: "3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
})
```